# React Native - How to combine TouchableWithoutFeedback with KeyboardAvoidingView?

Tags: react-native

This is my code:

```
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>

                <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container} behavior="padding" enabled>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>Login</Text>

                    <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" animating={this.state.isProcessing} />

                    <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                        <TextInput
                            style={styles.textInput}
                            onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({ email })}
                            value={this.state.email}
                            keyboardType="email-address"
                            textContentType="emailAddress"
                            placeholder="Email"
                            editable={!this.state.isProcessing}
                        />
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                        <TextInput
                            style={styles.textInput}
                            onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({ password })}
                            value={this.state.password}
                            secureTextEntry={true}
                            placeholder="Password"
                            editable={!this.state.isProcessing}
                        />
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            style={styles.button}
                            onPress={this.logIn.bind(this)}
                            disabled={this.state.isProcessing}
                        >
                            <Text style={{ color: '#fefffe' }}>Login</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </KeyboardAvoidingView>

            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

`Keyboard.dismiss` can work properly, but `KeyboardAvoidingView` does not work completely.

If I touch the TextInput, `KeyboardAvoidingView` will not adjust position based on the position of the keyboard.

Why does this happened?

Please help me. Thanks a lot.